# Java Problem in setting path (can't compile java in CMD)

Tags: java, cmd, path, javac

i tried to compile java by entering javac, even after setting path, it gave me the response below, if you could help me that would be great, thank you!

```
C:\Users\Hp>set path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_333\bin"

C:\Users\Hp>javac
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  -g                         Generate all debugging info
  -g:none                    Generate no debugging info
  -g:{lines,vars,source}     Generate only some debugging info
  -nowarn                    Generate no warnings
  -verbose                   Output messages about what the compiler is doing
  -deprecation               Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
  -classpath <path>          Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
  -cp <path>                 Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
  -sourcepath <path>         Specify where to find input source files
  -bootclasspath <path>      Override location of bootstrap class files
  -extdirs <dirs>            Override location of installed extensions
  -endorseddirs <dirs>       Override location of endorsed standards path
  -proc:{none,only}          Control whether annotation processing and/or compilation is done.
  -processor <class1>[,<class2>,<class3>...] Names of the annotation processors to run; bypasses default discovery process
  -processorpath <path>      Specify where to find annotation processors
  -parameters                Generate metadata for reflection on method parameters
  -d <directory>             Specify where to place generated class files
  -s <directory>             Specify where to place generated source files
  -h <directory>             Specify where to place generated native header files
  -implicit:{none,class}     Specify whether or not to generate class files for implicitly referenced files
  -encoding <encoding>       Specify character encoding used by source files
  -source <release>          Provide source compatibility with specified release
  -target <release>          Generate class files for specific VM version
  -profile <profile>         Check that API used is available in the specified profile
  -version                   Version information
  -help                      Print a synopsis of standard options
  -Akey[=value]              Options to pass to annotation processors
  -X                         Print a synopsis of nonstandard options
  -J<flag>                   Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
  -Werror                    Terminate compilation if warnings occur
  @<filename>                Read options and filenames from file
```

Comment: What are you expecting when you invoke `javac` with no arguments? If you had a problem with PATH btw, you would get an error message. That's a help message, which you got because `javac` thinks (quite rightly) that you need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fill `javac` with options. Meaning that you can't just call javac without a file to compile. when you write javac in terminal without any arguments, by default it will run `javac -help` and display the options you see.

To really see if it works:
Create a new java file.
To compile (in the same directory): `javac <java_file_name>.java`
To run: `java <java_file_name>`